# Calling list of instances in a function of a class

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am learning Python using "Learn Python the Hard Way". Programming is very new to me. I'm at exercise 42. I'm asked to do the following:

> Make some new relationships that are lists and dictionaries so you can also have "has-many" relationships.

I want the program to print the names of all of Frank's pets. However, I get an error saying `'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'callpet'`.

I understand the problem is that I'm using a list. When I write `frank.pet = satan` there is no problem at all. But I want Frank to have more than one pet, and I want the program to print the names of those pets.

This is the full code I am using:

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pet = None

    def callme(self):
        return self.name

    def petsyay(self):
        namepet = self.pet.callpet()        
        return namepet


class Pets(object):
    def __init__(self, petname):
        self.petname = petname

    def callpet(self):
        return self.petname


frank = Person("Frank")
poekie = Pets("Poekie")
satan = Pets("Satan")

frank.pet = [poekie, satan]

print frank.petsyay()
```

What I understand is that I need to split the list or something. So I've tried the following:

```
def callpet(self):
    for eachpet in petname:
        return self.petname
```

Put that just gets the same error. I'm confused, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're doing quite a lot wrong, your code doesn't make sense. The error message tells you exactly the problem - `self.pet` is **a list of pets**, you need to iterate over it to get to the objects that support `callpet`. I'd recommend you find a decent Python OOP tutorial to follow.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've edited to add I am learning Python using LPTHW.

Comment: You can no more call `callpet()` on a `list` of pets than you can go to the grocery store and buy a grocery list. You have to call `callpet()` on each item in the `list`, like you'd go through the grocery list and buy each individual item on it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, I understand the problem is I'm trying to do things with a list that can't be done with a list. I think I'm just trying to do something I'm not able to do yet...

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why I'm getting downvotes. This is an honest question and I was honestly trying to fix it myself to the best of my ability. Oh well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true after edits (do note that his return is sometimes a petname and sometime a list of petnames, this is not good): [If you call Mr. E's answer for a single Pets only you will most likely recieve an error `TypeError: 'Pets' object is not iterable`. His answer will only work as long as `self.pets` is a list and will fail when they're not.]

If you want to support singular and multiple Pets at the same time, either always make sure your `self.pet` is a `list` or make sure you check before you process them. Kepp in mind that it's important that you have a constant type output exiting your function because otherwise it makes other people's lives hard.

I recommend that you make `self.pets` a mandatory list in `__init__`

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pet = None

    def callme(self):
        return self.name

    def petsyay(self):
        if isinstance(self.pet, list):
            namepet = []
            for pet in self.pet:
                namepet.append(pet.callpet())
        elif isinstance(self.pet, Pets):
            namepet = []
            namepet.append(self.pet.callpet())
        else:
            raise ValueError("Not a correct type. Send Pets or list of Pets")
        return namepet


class Pets(object):
    def __init__(self, petname):
        self.petname = petname

    def callpet(self):
        return self.petname


frank = Person("Frank")
poekie = Pets("Poekie")
satan = Pets("Satan")

frank.pet = [poekie, satan]

print frank.petsyay()

frank.pet = poekie
frank.petsyay()
print frank.petsyay()
```

Comment: This is very helpful and helps me on my way to get new knowledge - excellent!

Answer (score 1):

I debugged your program and what was happening was that you did not have a setPets method in your person object so `self.pets` was never getting set with the list of pets. It was constantly `None`. I added a setPets method as well as updating the `petsYay` method to return a list. You could also use `yield` and return a generator to loop through outside of the class. Heres the updated code:

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = None

    def setPets(self, p):
        self.pets = p

    def callme(self):
        return self.name

    def petsyay(self):
        tempL = []
        if self.pets is not None:
            for pet in self.pets:
                 tempL.append(pet.callpet())
        return tempL
class Pets(object):
    def __init__(self, petname):
        self.petname = petname

    def callpet(self):
        return self.petname


frank = Person("Frank")
poekie = Pets("Poekie")
satan = Pets("Satan")
frank.setPets([poekie, satan])

print frank.petsyay()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `frank.pet` is a `list` of `Pets`. To do what you want you must redefine `petsyay` to work with a list of Pets, and return a list of names

```
def petsyay(self):
    return [p.callpet() for p in self.pet]
```

If you want to work with both lists of pets or single pet, you could handle the exception

```
def petsyay(self):
    try:
        return self.pet.callpet()
    except AtributeError: #Just handle the AttributeError to prevent hiding another exception
        return [p.callpet() for p in self.pet]
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems I'm trying to do something that's above my current ability. Because I don't understand the code you wrote yet :).

Comment: @MarijkeVonk Haha, well, in the first case it's creating a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with the names of the pets in the list.

In the second case it tries to return the name of the pet. If it doesn't work (Like in your code) will generate an [Exception](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) which you could handle to work with a list of pets as in the first case

Hope this helps you